# Triac wiring section

Tags: power, wiring, triac

When wiring the power cables in a house, normative says wires must be typically 2.5, 4 or 6 mm2 in section for 230 V and 10...40 A.

However, legs of a triac (thyristor, see [this one](https://www.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics/datasheets/switching_thyristors/littelfuse_thyristor_qxx15xx_qxx16xhx_datasheet.pdf.pdf) by example) are much smaller, around 0.3 mm2 for a 16 A element. Even smaller will be the conductive layer of the board where triac could be mounted.

Could someone help me to clarify this apparent contradiction?

Answer (score 0):

Excluding government regulations, the two factors to consider for low-frequency copper conductor cross-section are acceptable voltage drop and acceptable temperature rise. The house wiring consists of very long wires. The triac lead and PWB traces are very short and they should have a good thermal path to keep the temperature rise down.

Tables showing maximum allowed current for various PWB trace widths are only considering temperature rise. The PWB traces right at the part may need to be narrow, but you should quickly increase the width to as large as practical.